# Add to cart created at today rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

My db is postgresql and using rails 3.2.13, 
the method add_to_cart is not working as expected, 
I want to add to the cart created at today or create if it is not created, 
but it doesn't create a new one and adds to the cart created at 2-3 days ago sometimes, 
what is wrong in my code?

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base 
has_many :line_items 

scope :from_today, where("created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?",
                           Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day,
                           Time.zone.now.end_of_day)

 def self.add_to_cart(user_id)
   cart = Cart.from_today.first_or_create
   line_item = cart.line_items.where(user_id: user_id).first_or_initialize
   line_item.amount += 1
   line_item.save
 end
end
```

Comment: Try changing your scope to: `where(created_at: (Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)..(Time.zone.now.end_of_day))`

Comment: Could you try to wrap `where` query in a lambda function like `scope :from_today, -> { where(...) }`

Comment: @SergeyKishenin ok, i will try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have "dynamic data" in your scope. Check out [this article](http://www.stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/todays-gotcha-dynamic-data-in-rails-scopes/) to understand what's happening.

Your scope is executed at the initialization process but you need it to be executed at the runtime. The workaround is:

1. To use lambdas in the scope: `scope :from_today, -> { where(...) }`
2. Avoid using scopes and use a class method:

`def self.from_today
   where(...)
 end`

Also, when you query a range it would be better to pass an array or range as a value: `where(created_at: (Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)..(Time.zone.now.end_of_day))`

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be the format of your dates inside your scope. At the moment it'll return:

```
Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day
=> Mon, 28 Apr 2014 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

but in a database query you need it in the format:

```
Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day.to_s(:db)
=> "2014-04-28 00:00:00"
```

You might also need to surround the time with single quotes - give it a test and see.